# How do I lock a Microsoft SQL Server column so it can't be edited from the outside, but the database itself can edit the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I am trying to make a `Created` and a `Edited` column in every SQL Server table. I want to make it so that the `Created` column has the datetime of the row being created for the first time. And I want the `Edited` column to be the last datetime something in the row has been edited.

This is what I have:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Vragen
(
    VraagID    INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Tekstvraag VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Active     BIT          NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    Created    DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    Edited     DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CONSTRAINT Vragen_pk_VraagnummerID PRIMARY KEY (VraagID),
    CONSTRAINT Check_Tekstvraag CHECK (LEN(TRIM(Tekstvraag)) > 5 AND Tekstvraag LIKE '%?')
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER update_vragen_trigger
ON Vragen
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Vragen 
    SET Edited = GETDATE() 
    FROM Vragen 
    WHERE VraagID IN (SELECT VraagID FROM inserted)
END
```

This works fine, but how do I make it so it can't be edited from the outside? So that only the database itself can update those columns?

Comment: Handle that in your front end application, and don't give the user a place to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Column level security. When u say "from outside", that user must have a role assigned. That role should not have any write permissions(`update, insert` etc) on those columns. I guess this way you can reinforce the constraint. This [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/) has good example how to do that.